# Invalid Summary in NSString assignment

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to implement a simple calculator where I have to update the current operation (+, -, * etc) in a variable of type NSString. Current operation is received to the Model as a parameter.

```
 -(double)doOperation:(NSString *)operation withOperand:(double)operand
 {
     if (!currentOperation)
     {
         anOperand = operand;
     }   

     currentOperation = operation; //Invalid Summary in currentOperation; but + in operation
 }
```

What could be wrong in this? If direct assignment of pointers are not allowed for NSString, what is the alternate method?

**EDIT**

1. To be more precise, is it legal in iOs to assign NSString with = sign?
2. If not, what is the way to go.

Note: currentOperation is a private variable in Controller class and operation is a parameter to the method.

Here is the complete code

```
@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject {
    double anOperand;
    NSString * currentOperaion;
}

- (double) doOperation: (NSString *) operation 
           withOperand: (double) operand;

@end



@implementation CalculatorBrain


- (double) doOperation: (NSString *) operation 
           withOperand: (double) operand
{
    if (!currentOperaion)
    {
        anOperand = operand;
    }
    else if([currentOperaion isEqual: @"+"])
    {
        anOperand += operand;
    }
    else if([currentOperaion isEqual: @"-"])
    {
        anOperand -= operand;
    }
    else if([currentOperaion isEqual: @"*"])
    {
        anOperand *= operand;
    }
    else if([currentOperaion isEqual: @"/"])
    {
        anOperand /= operand;
    }

    currentOperaion = operation; //This is where the statement doesn't work as expected

    if ([currentOperaion isEqual: @"="])
    {
        currentOperaion = nil;
    }

    return anOperand;
}

@end
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific with what the "problem" is. Besides the obvious typo's, do mean that there are compile-time errors, or run-time errors? The method is also supposed to return a `double`, which you're not doing...

Comment: Your problem is not understood.please elaborate your problem.

Comment: Please have a look at the edited problem description.

Comment: Assigning NSString with `=` is perfectly legal. How is currentOperation declared?

Comment: To get useful answers you should post small samples that actually show the problem. Otherwise it's mostly going to be guesswork.

Comment: Ok. Let me edit it with the full code.

Comment: You are reusing the same `currentOperaion` string over multiple calls of your function, so you have to take ownership and also relinquish it on dealloc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To be more precise, is it legal in iOs to assign NSString with = sign?

Yes.

> What could be wrong in this?

You are not taking ownership of the string which will lead to problems if you want to use the instance later, see the [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1):

> You can take ownership of an object using `retain`.
>   Remember that an object may have more than one owner. Taking ownership of an object is your way of saying that you need it to be kept alive.

You could `-retain` the string, or `-copy` it to avoid mutation from external code, e.g.:

```
// in -doOperation::
[currentOperation release];
currentOperation = [operation copy]; // copy if operation might be mutable

// relinquish ownership:
- (void)dealloc {
    [currentOperation release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Also look into [declared properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

If currentOperation is declared as NSString, try

```
currentOperation = [NSString stringWithString:operand];
```

Comment: That assigns an autoreleased string to a member variable - as soon as the autorelease pool is drained the variable is an invalid reference.

Comment: Is he trying to use it outside the scope of the method? I haven't seen that code.

Comment: The variable is a private variable of type (NSString *) and has no alloc or init written.Its just declared. Another information is that the currentOperation is used within a single instance method.

Comment: @Saravanan: How about posting a more complete sample then that reproduces the problem? @Terry: Good point. Still, assigning autoreleased string instances to member variables definitely doesn't look right.