# NSString "invalid summary"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Ok, I have read a lot of posts and resources about this but I am STILL having the same issue. I have a few NSString variables that I need to be class-wide variables used in multiple places throughout the class. I have tried many combinations of settings. First of all, I do have the strings declared in the interface like so:

```
@interface iCodeViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {

    NSString *myString;
}
```

I have also added the property as follows (I have tried with and without the property and synthesizing)

```
@property (readwrite, retain) NSString *myString;
```

I have also tried, (nonatomic, retain), (nonatomic, copy), (readwrite, copy).

Then in the .m file:

```
@synthesize myString;
```

I have tried:

```
self.myString = @"whatever";
myString = @"whatever";
```

I have also tried with and without allocating memory to it by:

```
myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

What am I missing??

After I have 'supposedly' set the string variable in one method, I try to check it in another with `if ([myString isEqualToString:@"blah blah"])` and when I put in a breakpoint and hover over myString it is always showing 'invalid summary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
self.myString = [NSString  stringWithString:@"whatever"];
```

for more read the SO post

[Invalid Summary in NSString assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958504/invalid-summary-in-nsstring-assignment/5965562#5965562)

Answer (score 0):

Can you place the class code here? The way you are handling your myString is perfectly fine.
One possibility I can think of is that you are forgetting to return self from the init method.

There could be other possible memory related mess some where in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the invalid summary by initializing an NSMutableString to size 100 and only appending to it.  I found the problem went away when I called

```
[mutableString setString:@""];
```

prior to

```
[mutableString appendString:string];
```